# 'Always' block after every stage in declarative Jenkin's pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I need to run 'always' block which has a script, after every stage. So, what I have done is shown below. My question is, is there anyway I can have 'always' block just once  and then call after each stage rather than supplying the whole 'always script' after each stage?

```
pipeline {
agent { label '!master' }

stages {
    stage("Checkout Test") {
        steps {
            'Do somthing'
        }
    }
    stage('Test1') {
        steps {
            dir('test') {
                'Do something'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        *always {
            script {
                dir('test') {
                    Uploader(
                            'Do something'
                    )
                }
            }
        }*
    }

    stage('Test2') {
        steps {
            dir('test') {
                'Do something'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        *always {
            script {
                dir('test') {
                    Uploader(
                            'Do something'
                    )
                }
            }
        }*

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run as a post script you have to add the post block after each stage. But within that you can always call a method, saving some code repetition.

Another option is to call the post script method (runPostScript()) directly as the last step of the stage instead of adding a post script. But the caveat is that it may not execute all the time. If something within the stage fails, the method will not get executed.

```
        pipeline {
    agent { label '!master' }
    
    stages {
        stage("Checkout Test") {
            steps {
                'Do somthing'
            }
        }
        stage('Test1') {
            steps {
                dir('test') {
                    'Do something'
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            *always {
                script {
                    runPostScript()
                }
            }*
        }
    
        stage('Test2') {
            steps {
                dir('test') {
                    'Do something'
                }
            }
        }
    
        post {
            *always {
                script {
                    runPostScript()
                }
            }*
    
        }
    }
    }

def runPostScript(){
           'do something'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, the "global" post section missbehaves:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('A') { echo 'A' }
        stage('B') { echo 'B' }
    }
    post { always { echo 'P' } }
}
```

In the log, I can see:
A
P
B
P

I would expect:
A
B
P

The documentation is unclear...